# $x^p - x+ a$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_p [x]$ if $a\neq 0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

I want to show that $f(x)=x^p - x+ a$ is irreducible  in $\mathbb{F}_p [x]$ if $a \neq 0$. I know that if $b$ is a root of $f$, then $b+1$ is also a root of $f$. Can I use this fact to prove that $f$ is irreducible? Any hints or reference are appreciated.

Comment: That's a good start. But this question has been asked many times. In the dupe target there are several nice ways of getting there (mine is among the least thrilling).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We know $f$ has no roots in $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Suppose $g(x)\in\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ is a degree $d>1$ irreducible factor of $f(x)$.  Then $g(x+m)$ for all $m\in\mathbb{F}_p$ are irreducible factors of $f(x)$. They can't be all distinct because that would be too many: $\prod_{m\in\mathbb{F}_p}g(x+m)$ would be a factor of $f$ but it has degree $p\deg g>p$.  So $g(x)=g(x+m)$ for some $m\in\mathbb{F}_p^\times$, but that would mean $g(x+n)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{F}_p$ are all equal, so $g$ has degree $\geq p$ (and divisible by $p$) by counting roots.